# Perl exp_continue function how does it work?

Tags: perl, switch-statement, expect, router, continue

I am actually refactoring the code of some of my co-workers and i have a question.
Searching the web didn't gave me anything good so there it is :

I am spawning a new Expect to connect to every router & switch.
Each time it connects, the expect works like this :

```
  $exp->expect ($timeout, 
        [qr/[Pp]assword:\s*/ => sub { 
            #Some work 1
        }],
        [qr/.*Are you sure you want to continue connecting.*/ => sub { 
            $exp->send("yes\n");
            exp_continue;
        }],
        [qr/.*refused.*/ => sub { 
            # some code 3
        }],
    );
```

I want it to start again from the first statement, probably need some recursion.
When "exp_continue" is reached, **what happens?** will it start from the first qr/ or will it continue to the third?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never worked with the perl expect package but according to the author it closely resembles expect.

Extract taken from Exploring Expect by Don Libes:

> When executed as an expect action, the command exp_continue causes control to be
>   continued inside the current expect command. expect continues trying to match the
>   pattern, but from **where it left off after the previous match**. expect effectively repeats
>   its search as if it had been invoked again.

A quick test would be to have it check for the password regex before and after the connection regex, and then displaying a msg to show which block was executed.

Comment: Yup, after some tries, it appears that the exp_continues starts from the beginning of the previous expect.